# Convert C++ to VB6

Tags: c++, vb6

I basically have a script in C++, and want to convert it to VB6. The help i need is something like this

```
dim SomeString as String '--> what is the c++ equivalent
#include<stdio.h> 
'// what is the vb6 equivalent
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE 1024
```

if i can get a syntax comparison sheet sort of that compares very well, It would be OK.

Comment: If you don't already have experience with C++, which you clearly don't, then you don't have a chance in the world of succeeding at this.

Comment: Do you know VB6? If you know at least one of the two languages my suggestion is learning the other --find some tutorial and go through it, you may not need to master the language, but you surely need to understand what it does. If you do not know either, apply iteratively: learn one language, then the other. It might not be the fastest way, but the task is not simple.

Comment: Just like spoken and written languages, there is not always a direct translation from one to the other.

Comment: @Johathan: "viewed

4 times"… and 4 votes on your comment. How is that even possible? (you can't upvote yourself!)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: race condition obviously. It would be bloody expensive to retrieve all information for a single page in a single transaction.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Am a pro in vb6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i can get a syntax comparison sheet sort of that compares very well, i'ld be ok

VB unfortunately misses lots of advanced constructs, thus C++ and many other programming languages generally can not be translated into it.

Normal practice in the case is to compile C++ code into [an ActiveX component](http://msmvps.com/blogs/pauldomag/archive/2006/08/16/107758.aspx) and use the [component from VB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315847).

Answer (score 1):

Does sound like it'll be tough if it's a non-trivial program.  I stumbled upon http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages/Vrs.html#VrsCmprs - is that the kind of thing you're hoping for?  Good luck!

Comment: This is a good start for me , thanks. But in general, i need a crash course in c++(like learn c++ in 24 hrs). am a pro in vb6